# How to include external jars in maven jar build process?

Tags: maven, jar, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin

I want to build a .jar file with dependencies in maven. Unfortunately I have to include some external .jars in my buildpath. When I now try to build this project with maven package I will get an error that those external .jars are not found.

How to adapt my pom file to add those jars?
current:

```
    <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/lib</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2-beta-4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can include the external jars in your build path as dependency with `<scope>system</scope>`
.

Check this [link](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#System_Dependencies)

Comment: it looks about right, but what if it's not a part of the JDK, as the example cites. What if you want to reference a JAR that's in the same directory as the pom for example? (in project folder)

Comment: Well and fine, BUT that dep will then NOT be packaged with your jar/war.

Comment: This is deprecated now, according to Maven official page.

Comment: @DonCheadle 9 instead `${java.home}` you may use `{project.basedir}`.

Answer (score 8):

You need use below command to add external jar into .m2 folder

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=[JAR] -DgroupId=[some.group] -DartifactId=[Some Id] -Dversion=1.0.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

This will add the given jar in to your .m2 folder. After that go to pom.xm and just add the dependency with given group id, artifact id and version.

Comment: In Windows I had to surround all parameter values with double quotes

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution for this is to add it into local maven repository

One way to do is via mvn install commands as suggested in previous post .

Another easy way is,

1. In your eclipse ide right click on project select Maven option.
2. Select Install or deploy an artifact to a maven repository option and click on next.
3. Click on browse next to the Artifact file checkbox & select your jar file.
4. Enter the GroupId and ArtifactId and version ensure generate pom & create checksum are checked & packaging is jar

Click on finish, Wallah!!! your job is done the jar is added in your local repository which you can define in setting.xml or m2 directory.

Now just add the simple maven dependency as per the GroupId,ArtifactId & jar version that you have entered as per the import and that's it your external jar will be packaged by maven.